# Using Tensorflow Hub with TF2 and Universal Sentence Encoder v4

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Trying to use TF2 and the Universal Sentence Encoder.  I use the same code below and it works for a few other Hub models (nnlm-20,50,128), but not for the USE v4.  I think it has to do with the output shape (due to the error and what model.summary() shows), because the output is a dictionary of {'outputs':(None,512)}:

```
embed_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/4",input_shape=[],dtype=tf.string,trainable=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(embed_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                validation_data=validation_dataset,
                epochs=30,
                verbose=1
               )
```

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_input to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Comment: can you provide a sample input dataset and what exactly you are trying to do. I might be able to solve it for you.